# Authentication issue while Calling a WCF through a proxy on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, iis-6, iis-7.5

I am writing a webservice using .Net 3.5.

My webservice consumes an external WCF, to get to it I have to pass through our proxy server that requires authentication.
To do that I use this code:

```
WebProxy wproxy = new WebProxy(ProxyServer, Port);
wproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUser, ProxyPassword, Domain);
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = wproxy;
```

The server I need to run my webservice on is a IIS 7.5 webserver (Windows Server 2008 R2 standard), when I run it there I get the following message (this is the response from the external WCF) :

> **The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) authenticationrequired**

For testing I also tried to run it on a older server using IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003 R2 standard) and on this server it worked fine.

So anyone have an idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved this problem by installing .NET 4 on the IIS server, the server that had the IIS 6 already had .NET 4 installed.

I still don't know why this happend since my program is using .NET 3.5.
Could possbly be that .NET 4 fixes something in the base files of .NET or changes some defualt behaviour.